# Attempt to invoke virtual method `MaterialEditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaterialEditText edtNewUser, edtNewPassword, edtNewEmail; //pentru Sign up
    MaterialEditText edtUser, edtPassword, edtEmail; //pentru Sign in

    Button btnSignUp, btnSignIn;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference users;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = database.getReference("Users");

        edtUser = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUser);
        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showSignUpDialog();
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn(edtUser.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn(final String user, final String pwd) {
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(user).exists()){
                    if(!user.isEmpty()){
                        User login = dataSnapshot.child(user).getValue(User.class);
                        if(login.getPassword().equals(pwd))
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login ok!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Parola incorecta!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Va rog introduceti username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username-ul nu exista!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showSignUpDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Sign up");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Introduceti informatiile necesare");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View sign_up_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_up_layout,null);

        edtNewUser = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewUserName);
        edtNewEmail = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewEmail);
        edtNewPassword = (MaterialEditText)sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewPassword);


        alertDialog.setView(sign_up_layout);
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp);

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                final User user = new User(edtNewUser.getText().toString(),
                        edtNewPassword.getText().toString(),
                         edtNewEmail.getText().toString());

                users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUserName()).exists())
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User-ul exista deja!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else{
                            users.child(user.getUserName()).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inregistrat cu success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/info_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/edtNewUserName"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
                />

            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/edtNewPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/info_login"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@id/btn_sign_up"
                android:text="Sign up"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@id/btn_sign_in"
                android:text="Sign in"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help me! I've tried anything I knew but nothing works
The program I work in is ANDROID STUDIO. I need to solve this to finish my app.

```
signIn(edtUser.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString());
```

This is the line that gives me ERROR. If I comment this line the app works properly but I need it for the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your `edtUser` `MaterialEditText` and `edtPassword` are not present in your xml file, you have to change the ids in xml file to match the Activity ids, or remplace

```
edtUser = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUser);
edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
```

by :

```
edtUser = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNewUserName);
edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNewPassword);
```